# what this (int**)&p; mean in the statement?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

This code is practice code for pointers. But I am not understanding the `(int**)&p;` means in this code.

```
void fun(void *p);

int i;

int main()
{
  void *vptr;
  vptr = &i;
  fun(vptr);
  return 0;
}
void fun(void *p)
{
    int **q;
    q = (int**)&p;
    printf("%d\n", **q);
}
```

Please elaborate how it is evaluated.

Comment: Isn't it just casting a pointer to `p` (therefore making it `void**`) to `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a type cast, that interprets the value of `&p`, which has type `void **`, as instead having type `int **` which is the type of the variable the value is stored in.

The cast is necessary, since `void **` is not the same as `void *` and does not automatically convert to/from other (data) pointer types. This can be confusing.

Comment: Thank you to make me understand

Answer (score 2):

&p being of type void**, is being casted to type of int** which is to be assigned to q.

> **SIDE-NOTE** : *"Any pointer can be assigned to a pointer to void. It can then be cast back to its original
>   pointer type. When this happens the value will be equal to the original pointer value."*
>
> Be careful when using pointers to void. If you cast an arbitrary
>   pointer to a pointer to void, there is nothing preventing you from
>   casting it to a different pointer type.

Comment: This is false. `p` is not being "casted back", the value that is being cast is  `&p`.

Comment: @unwind - Sorry, my mistake, it was a "slip of finger", actually habituated to type casted back, hence mis-typed it. Thanks for reminding, I have improved it.